# How to catch "too many attempt" exception in a middleware Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, throttling

I am building my API and I successfuly managed to catch some errors on a middleware I set up around my routes like following :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => \App\Http\Middleware\ExceptionHandlerMiddleware::class], function() {

    Route::resource('/address', 'AddressController');

    Route::resource('/country', 'CountryController');

    Route::resource('/phone', 'PhoneController');

    Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
});
```

The middleware manage to catch the following exceptions :

- `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException`
- `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`
- `Exception`

Which is great. I am also aware of a throttle mecanism that control the number of attempt in a route. So with postman I attacked my route `http://localhost:8000/api/user` until I get the `too many attemp` error.

The exception is throwed in the file located at :

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php
```

And I also managed to get the type of exception it throws thanks to this [forum topic](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-use-laravel-throttle) : `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\TooManyRequestsHttpException`.

So in the end my middleware looks like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\TooManyRequestsHttpException;
use Exception;

class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $output = $next($request);

        try {
            if( ! is_null( $output->exception ) ) {
                throw new $output->exception;
            }

            return $output;
        }
        catch( TooManyRequestsHttpException $e ) {
            return response()->json('this string is never showed up', 429);
        }
        catch( ValidationException $e ) {           
            return response()->json('validation error' 400);
        }
        catch( ModelNotFoundException $e ) {            
            return response()->json('not found', 404);
        }
        catch( \Exception $e ) {            
            return response()->json('unknow', 500);
        }
    }
}
```

You see the line `this string is never showed up` ? In fact it is never showed up, the original throttle exception from Illuminate always take the front.

**QUESTION**

How can I properly override the base error in a way that I could possibly (if possible) catch any exception without having to modify the illuminate file (in case of updates...) ?

Runing laravel 5.4.

**EDIT**

I cannot afford manually updating `app/Http/Exception` files because my app will be shipped as a Service Provider for my futures others project. Also, I do not prefer taking the risk to erase some previous configuration on these files, as other "basic" routes in `routes.php` may have their own exception catching procedures.

Comment: Exact version of Laravel is needed, since error handling has changed over the years.

Comment: You may want to re-read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#the-exception-handler that part and come back if that does not work for you.

Comment: I read updated question, take a step back what if multiple packages want to "handle too many requests" what will Laravel do? Well it will break, so you need to handle HTTP based exceptions at *application level* not at service provider level and do not `try..catch` in middleware its not good solution. Think about it out of the box for a while. "Global" handler is the only way, you may check for request data and determine that it was meant for "your package" and handle it and if not just re-throw it as is.

Comment: For laravel 5.6, you just have to handle the https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/Exceptions/ThrottleRequestsException.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way to achieve that is to use `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        if (request()->expectsJson()) {
            switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {
                case 404:
                    return response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid request or url.'], 404);
                    break;
                case '500':
                    return response()->json(['message' => 'Server error. Please contact admin.'], 500);
                    break;

                default:
                    return $this->renderHttpException($exception);
                    break;
            }
        }
    } else if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        if (request()->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' =>$exception->getMessage()], 404);
        }
    } {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

In this demo you can add more Exception like `} else if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {` and tackle them.